# For fetching data from server for React frontend should I use websockets or api calls?

Tags: reactjs, api, websocket, redux, web-frontend

I am very new to frontend. I do not exactly know how react frontends work. Assuming I have a frontend written in React that needs to refresh data on the page say every ten seconds, can I achieve that by making api calls to a server every ten seconds or open a websocket with it and make the server push data? These are not notifications! They are just statistical data that needs to be updated on the page in realtime. Please tell me whats a good way to achieve this.

Comment: I would recommend just making an API call whenever you need to refresh the data. Opening up and maintaining a websocket connection just to refresh data seems to be overkill imo

Comment: The first question is what kind of backend do you have or can you have? Websockets are easily supported with technologies like node.js, a lot less when using php for instance. Also, if you want uptimes “in real time”, that means you have updates coming in that can trigger a refresh. In that case sockets can help reduce the load on the server, but it really depends on what needs to be done for each update. You will have to share more details.

Comment: Node js backend service that holds the data. It is a simple page with graphs that needs to be updated with a fresh batch of data that is collected realtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Websockets are interesting when you want data to be pushed from your server to your client, i.e. when the client doesn't know when new data will be available. In your case, it seems that simple API calls will be enough.